# Cannot delete file nor folder

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to delete a file from a folder on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian, but I keep getting errors.

Here are some of the steps I took
(I replaced the file name with `foo` and the folder name with `folder`)

```
 > ls -al 
 total 4032
 drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    4096 Jun 22 19:00  .
 drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    4096 Jun 22 19:43  ..
 -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4120032 Jun 18 20:02 foo
 > rm [TAB] (auto completes to file name)
 rm: cannot remove foo: No such file or directory
```

```
  > rm -i *
  sure you want to delete the only file in /complete/path/folder? y
  rm: remove regular file foo? y
  rm: cannot remove foo: No such file or directory
```

Also tried removing the folder itself

```
  > cd ..
  > rm -rf folder
  rm: cannot remove folder: Directory not empty
```

Tried to check if anything was holding the file, but I got no output

```
  > lsof foo
```

As request, here is the ouput of `ls -alR foo`

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4120032 Jun 18 20:02 foo
```

Is there anything else I can do to unlock and delete this file (or folder)?

Comment: What are the permissions and owners of the parent directory (`.`), the foo directory, and any directories in `foo`? FYI, you used `foo` in your initial commands but `folder` in the next example. These really ought to be consistent in your question.

Comment: The output from `ls -l` is always much more informative when investigating problems relating to file and folder permissions and properties. Please [edit] your question to show the output of `ls -al`

Comment: @JimL. Even better would be `ls -alR foo` although it is not clear if we're looking at `foo` or at `folder`.

Comment: Included the output of `ls -al` as well as `ls -alR foo`. @doneal24, `foo` should be the file, `folder` is the folder

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's the file system? Did you check for fs errors? Also, you could share the output of `namei -l /full/path/to/file`.